# How to say "If you would like to know any updates , you can always call or message me"

Tags: usage, vocabulary, culture

According to my understanding, *“update”* is translated to “更新” . But this seems to be in the context of Software。 Eg. Software *update*, OS *update* ,etc.
But how would you convey update in the following scenario : There is a customer who wants to do online trading.
He has submitted some documents which need to be checked,translated and verified before he starts trading. The whole process may take up to 4 days.
The customer needs to be told that if there's an *update* , he will be informed by mail. Also, if he wants an *update* as to where the process has reached, 
he can send a text or a mail. In this scenario, how do we accurately convey the message with or without using the translation for "*Update*" ? 

One way I thought could be using 流程有事的话我会通知您。您有问题的话也您通过微信或邮件跟我联系. Any suggestions or alternatives ?

Comment: 进展 is appropriate. 欲获知后续进展如何，您可随时电话或邮件与我方联系。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

如果您想要了解后续进展的话，可以随时电话或邮件联系我。

Toosky Hierot's comment ”欲获知后续进展如何“ sounds a bit too literary to me. I think "如果您想要了解后续进展的话" is a more common way to say it, though I agree 进展 or 后续进展 is the right word choice here